# Show that the gamma distribution isn't stable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I'm trying to show that the gamma and poisson distributions are not stable using the fact that a r.v. X is stable if $\forall$ $c_{1}>0$ and $c_{2}>0$, $\exists$ $a>0$ e $b\in \mathbb{R}^d$ such that\
\begin{equation*}
 e^{i\langle b,u\rangle}\phi_{X}(au)=\phi_{X}(c_{1}u)\phi_{X}(c_{2}u).
\end{equation*}

Suppose X has gamma distribution with parameters $\alpha$ and $\beta$ than you have \
\begin{equation*}
\phi_{X}(c_{1}u)\phi_{Y}(c_{2}u) =  \bigg(1-\frac{ic_{1}u}{\beta}\bigg)^{-\alpha}\cdot \bigg(1-\frac{ic_{2}u}{\beta}\bigg)^{-\alpha}\end{equation*}
and you have to show that $\exists$  $c_{1}>0$ and $c_{2}>0$ for which that expression does not hold.

I'm stuck showing that it cannot be
\begin{equation*}
 e^{ibu}\bigg(1-\frac{iau}{\beta}\bigg)^{-\alpha}=\bigg(1-\frac{ic_{1}u}{\beta}\bigg)^{-\alpha}\cdot \bigg(1-\frac{ic_{2}u}{\beta}\bigg)^{-\alpha}
\end{equation*}

I know it is trivial but I cannot for the life of me find a way to justify it. Same with the Poisson

Comment: Typesetting tip:  To obtain $\mathbb{R}$, type `$\mathbb{R}$`.

Comment: I was thinking maybe this isn't the right way to look at it. I don't know if this checks out but: suppose X,Y are $gamma(\alpha, \beta)$ distributed. We know that $c_{1}$X is $gamma(\alpha, \beta / c_{1})$ distributed. So if I have $c_{1}X+c_{2}Y$, the only way $aZ+b$ is gamma(\alpha, \beta) distributed is to have $c_{1}=c_{2}=a$ suppose they are all equal to 1. then you have X+Y and that is $gamma(2\alpha, \beta)$ distributed, and that's a contraddiction because you wanted Z to be distributed with the same parameters as X and Y, but the shape has changed from $\alpha$ to $2\alpha$